# permissions on upload folder not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, php

I have a php script which uploads images to a folder.

I have these permissions on the upload folder:

```
  drwxrwxr--  4 user user   4096 2010-06-02 16:20 temp_images
```

Shouldn't these permissions be enough for files to be uploaded to the folder?

But this doesn't work.

It only works when I set the permissions to 777.

"user" is added to the www-data group, still no luck.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your folder is owned by the user and group **user**.  If apache is running as a different account, perhaps **www-data** then apache will not be able to write there.  Adding the **user** account to the **www-data** group would mean that **user** is permitted to write in folders that the **www-data** group owns and is set for rw.  If you want apache to write to the folder the group **user** owns the apache service account must be a member of the **user** group.

Answer (score 0):

If safe_mode is on, then user should be the apache/php user unless you set safe_mode_gid to on where check is done on group instead of user

Comment: what do you mean? if safe_mode is off, then apache user doesn't matter?

Comment: see Zoredache answer, I miss readed something in your question

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the directory should be the effective userid of the web servers. Try changing the ownership, then you can set the permissions to 700, 750, or 755.

chown www-data temp_images